# Module of eventually zero sequences over a Jacobson algebra is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Consider the Jacobson algebra $R =k \langle x, y\rangle /(xy − 1)$, where $k$ is a ﬁeld. Let $k^ω$ be
the R-module whose elements are inﬁnite sequences in $k$, with $y$ acting as the right
shift operator, and $x$ the left shift operator. I want to show that the submodule $_{R}M ≤ k^ω$ of
eventually zero sequences is a simple $R$-submodule.

To begin with, Let $N\le M$ be a nonzero left submodule and take $z\in N-\{0\}$. Then $z=(z_1,z_2,\dots)$ is an eventually zero sequence and $Rx$ is a left $R$-module (and left ideal). We only need to show $Rz=_{R}M$.

Can anyone show me how to continue from here? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nonzero module $M$ is simple if and only if, for every $z\in M$, $Rz=M$.

Let $z\ne0$, $z\in M$. Then we can assume the last nonzero term in $z$ is $1$. Then with left shifts we can say that the sequence $(1,0,0,\dotsc)\in Rz$. Hence, for every $a\in k$, $(a,0,0,\dotsc)\in Rz$. With right shifts we can move $a$ wherever we please.

An eventually zero sequence is a (finite) sum of sequences of this kind.